# I use x=a+x-x^2 and set g(x)=a+x-x^2 to find the positive square root of the positive parameter a

Tags: c++

```
// Convergence to a root of an equation

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

/* compute g(x) with parameter a */
double g(double a, double x) {
double y=0.0;
y=a+x-x*x;
return y;
}

/* compute the term x_n in the sequence given x0 and the parameter a */
double nthterm(double a, double x0, int n) {
for(int i=0;i<=n-1;i++) x0=g(a,x0);
return x0;
}

int main () {
  double a; // parameter
  int n; // number of steps to do
  double x0; // initial guess
  cout << "input a,x0,n: " << endl;
  cin >> a >> x0 >> n;
  cout << "param a=" << a << " guess=" << x0 << " number of terms=" << n << endl;
  cout << nthterm(a,x0,n) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I use x=a+x-x^2 and set g(x)=a+x-x^2 to find the positive square root of the positive parameter a.
It compile well, but I can't get the right answer from my code.

Comment: Are you sure that your series converges?

Comment: Yes,but I really can not get a better accuracy for large n.

Comment: Tell me your test values. And what are you expect?

Comment: Is this an accuracy issue or are your answers completely different from the "expected" answers?

Comment: a=2 x0=1.5 n=10 100 1000 10000,then the result is 1.25872  2.24745  2.24702  2.24698

Comment: Is 1.25872 currect? Because I got this answer with your code.

Comment: The answer is completely different from the expected one for large n.

Comment: 1.25872 is closed to the expected answer.But in most cases,it is completely different.

Comment: Tell me what is currect result for a=2,x0=1.5 and n=10000? Sorry but in code I don't see mistake. I try figure out math problem.

Comment: I also do not know the correct result.But I think it should be expected to be near the square root of 2.However,for large n ,the answer is near to 2,24.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this series;  where did you find it? AFAICT, it converges for 0 <= a <= 1 and for correct guesses beyond that.

Comment: I think you have wrong formul. Look Xaver answer. This it works.

Comment: In fact,the following is the requirement.And I write my code following the tips.< For the starting equation x^2−a (asking us to find the positive square root of the positive parameter a) we might rearrange to x=a+x−x2 and set g(x)=a+x−x2. Given a starting point x0 the sequence can be computed and (we hope) a√ estimated to better accuracy as xn for larger n>

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the series you create with *nthterm* does not converge. Try to change the line

```
y=a+x-x*x;
```

to

```
y=(x+a/x)/2;
```

EDIT: The code works if and only if the start value is not zero. For positive start values you get the positive square root; for negative start values you get the negative square root.

Comment: And for better result you can add `setprecision`. Here is all [example](http://cpp.sh/5d5yt) and work very nice.